# Can you see old messages on a SIM card free phone?

Tags: iphone, messages

Can you still see old messages on an old SIM card for an iPhone 4? Mine died a few months ago, AT&T techs took out the SIM card when they gave me my new phone, but now my parents are trying to "fix" my old phone to be nosy! Yikes!

Comment: Messages are not stored on the SIM card.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't wipe your phone before removing the SIM card, your messages (and everything else) will still be on the phone. If your phone is still registered in "Find my iPhone" and has network connectivity (either through a new SIM card or through WiFi), you can wipe it from your iCloud account. See [iCloud: Find My iPhone overview](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2696?viewlocale=en_US) and [iCloud: Erase your device](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) for details about the procedure.

Comment: Thank you! But even if it's still off I can swipe it from my iCloud? And wouldn't the tech people go ahead and swipe it for me?

Comment: And how do I wipe it in my iCloud? Cuz I don't think it was ever backed up

Comment: You can't remotely wipe a phone which does have no connectivity at all (or is turned off). As for At&T, I don't know what their standard procedure is.

Comment: Ooh... What if it was never on Find My IPhone? I'm screwed?

Comment: Depending on the content of your messages and your relationship with your parents, this might very well be the case.